# Spark data conversion issue when predicting with Horovod KerasEstimator()

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pyspark, horovod

I'm training a Keras Model to build a recommender system and running it on Spark with Horovod and `hvd.KerasEstimator()`.

Here is my Estimator :

```
keras_estimator = hvd.KerasEstimator(
  num_proc=2,
  store=store,
  model=model,
  optimizer=optimizer,
  loss='mse',
  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
  feature_cols=['userID','itemID'],
  label_cols=['rating'],
  batch_size=512,
  epochs=5,
  verbose=1)

keras_model = keras_estimator.fit(train_df).setOutputCols(['rating_prob'])
```

The predict function is just :

`pred_df = keras_model.transform(test_df)`

The model is trained without any problem and I am able to get loss for every epochs but I struggle with predictions!

The predict function doesn't print any error and seems to work but the pred_df is impossible to manipulate.

I tried to do :

`pred_df.show()` or `pred_df.toPandas()` but everything raise the same error below :

*"org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'ValueError: cannot convert Spark data Type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DecimalType'> to native python type'"*

I dont understand because my train_df and test_df have the same types !

I've tryed changing types with :

```
# reset data types to integer and float for tensorflow
train_df = train_df.withColumn("itemID",col("itemID").cast(IntegerType())) \
    .withColumn("userID",col("userID").cast(IntegerType())) \
    .withColumn("rating",col("rating").cast(FloatType()))

test_df = test_df.withColumn("itemID",col("itemID").cast(IntegerType())) \
    .withColumn("userID",col("userID").cast(IntegerType())) \
    .withColumn("rating",col("rating").cast(FloatType()))
```

[see data types here :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17bCJ.png)

But the error is still here..

Below is an example of my data :

[train_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aba88.png)

Can you help me solve this issue please ?

Thanks in advance

I just tried to change column types but it doesn't change anything